# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue - Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS - 4.15.0-48-generic

Tags: 16.04, server, kernel, java

Please let us know when will be the next kernal release, One of our production machine which runs Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with kernal 4.15.0-48-generic builds are getting failed. the same issue happened on 14 after upgrade kernal issue got resolved.

```
Error:
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not create ConcurrentG1RefineThread
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /build/jenksvc/workspace/product_eng_-keys_Ubuntu16_test/LA.UM.7.2/LINUX/android/log.log

jenksvc@SONIC:/build/jenksvc/workspace$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                  = 1024                                  {pd product} {default}
   size_t ErgoHeapSizeLimit                        = 0                                        {product} {default}
   size_t HeapSizePerGCThread                      = 87241520                                 {product} {default}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 2147483648                               {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t LargePageHeapSizeThreshold               = 134217728                                {product} {default}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 32178700288                              {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 8766152                               {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 121446044                             {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 121446044                             {pd product} {ergonomic}
     intx ThreadStackSize                          = 1024                                  {pd product} {default}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                        = 1024                                  {pd product} {default}
openjdk version "9"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9+181-android4627429)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181-android4627429, mixed mode)
```

Comment: openjdk9 (as well as Oracle Java SE 9) has reached end of life. Consider using a supported java version.

Comment: Build only work on java 9, that's the reason we are not upgrading.. have any any idea when the next kernal will release? current version is 4.15.0-48-generic

Comment: You can backout to a previous release of the kernel...